# Int Variable inside Nvarchar Statement

Tags: sql-server

The following code sends error.

@resp2 is INT, it's the result of a sum preiously done. So now I want to update some row in another table using a dinamic statement.

```
SET @SQL = 'update TelepromTableNamesInfo set [Resp] = '+@RESP2+'
                where nombre = ''' + @TableWBraq + ''''
EXEC (@SQL)
```

First thing I've tried is '''+@resp2+''' But I don't want it be

> ' variable value '

since it's an INT value and there's no need for ''

The error makes sence. I can't put some INT value into a string. I'd use cast or convert but how can I do it inside the statement?
Or maybe I'm approaching the update from the wrong perspective?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Solved.

```
'+ cast(@RESP2 as nvarchar(7))+'
```

It was easier than I thought, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @SQL = 'update TelepromTableNamesInfo set [Resp] = '+ CAST(@RESP2 AS VARCHAR(50)) +'
                where nombre = ''' + @TableWBraq + ''''
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Yes! I was trying it the second before you wrote it. Thanks a lot, That was it.

Answer (score 0):

May be single quote is creating the problem. Please give a try the following:

```
SET @SQL = 'update TelepromTableNamesInfo set [Resp] = '+@RESP2+
                'where nombre = '"' + @TableWBraq + '"'
EXEC (@SQL)
```